# Retrieve LDAP server type

Tags: java, ldap

i want to know if there is a way to retrieve the connected ldap server type (openldap or active directory)

this below my connection method

```
public DirContext ldapUserConnect(String serverUrl, int serverPort, String serverType, String userDn,
        String userPassword, boolean binaryAttribute) throws NamingException {
    // connect to ldap server using ldap_server table data

    if ((userDn != null && !userDn.isEmpty()) || (userPassword != null && !userPassword.isEmpty())) {
        Map<String, String> environment = getLdapEnvironement(serverUrl, serverPort, serverType, binaryAttribute);
        // connect with user account
        environment.put(javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userDn);
        environment.put(javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, userPassword);
        return new InitialDirContext((Hashtable<String, String>) environment);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The general approach is to examine the `rootDSE` entry; however, there is no guarantee that all LDAP server vendors support this method. [Determine LDAP Server Vendor](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Determine%20LDAP%20Server%20Vendor) provides descriptions for several LDAP "flavors" and determining their vendor name/version.